# Can I limit memory & cpu used per docker container?

Tags: docker, memory, cpu

I was wondering if there's a way to limit or cap the max memory & processing power used by docker containers on host level. I'm under the impression that the memory options only add provided memory at container launch, but do not limit it permanently.

As I use containers with dotnet apps (hosted dlls), mono'd/wine'd exes, java apps & linux deamons, it would be great if I could make sure that, for instance, continues java memory allocation would not make other containers crash. I'm using java memory options (xms, xmx) for these containers now, and am doing similar to the other containers. I'm lacking a docker based system to manage and monitor cpu & memory.
Also, percentile scaling for memory & cpu would be useful, allowing one container to grab a lot of processing power & memory at peak moments. I can monitor this on host process level, not on docker level.

And I'm not even talking about a multi-host setup (swarm, rancher, kubernetes) yet.
Or is my question too general?

Answer (score 7):

The docker run command includes [options to limit memory and cpu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources), in particular the `-c` and `-m` options.

With a compose file and swarm mode (which can be a single node swarm cluster), these are configured with a [resources section per service](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources):

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 50M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 20M
```

For docker-compose support, you can use the [version 2 syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources) for a similar result:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
 test:
    image: busybox:latest
    command: tail -f /dev/null

    cpus: '0.50'
    mem_limit: '50M'
```

Comment: Note that the resources section in the compose file will only work in swarm mode

Comment: @Mim-nim good point. I updated the answer to include the `docker-compose` version.

Comment: the limit on deploy on swarm mode is for all the service or just by single containers?

Comment: @Darwin the limit is on each container. So multiply by the number of replicas to estimate your cluster requirements.

Comment: N.B. Doesn't work on 2, you'll need 2.2 specifically